# How do I convert individual images within a folder to text with Tesseract, but keep them as individual files with the same name?

Tags: command-prompt, tesseract

I'm aware how to use Tesseract the usual way with Command Prompt, using "tesseract (filename.extension) (filename.txt)". My issue is I have a large amount of images that need converted. I know you can use a batch file to combine the seperate images into one file of text, but I would like to keep them in individual files, with the same file names as they previously had. Is there a way to do this with Windows' Command Prompt, or would I need to use something like Python?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @user898678 Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g.:

```
 for /r %a in (*.png) do tesseract "%a" "%~na" -l eng
```